# Enums behaving anomaly in C#

Tags: c#, enums, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I was programing a school project (implement search algorithms) and I got stuck with the following problem :

There is a variable called action which is of the type enum Actions { esquerda = 0, abaixo = 1, direita = 2, acima = 3}.  After one of the search algorithms expand the neighbors of a given state (Property called Neighbours does the process), it call a method (Expansion()), which get possible neighbors and return as a list. The thing is after the return, WITHOUT DOING ABSOLUTLY NOTHING the value of the variable action aberrantly change after the first read in debug mode.

The line : List temp = Expansion();
after called and the variable temp be filled, when you read the value action of any element of the temp list for the second time, it changes its values to the last item of the enum (acima).

```
public class PuzzleState : Search.Node
    {
        private States[,] actualState;

        private int empLinePos;
        private int empColumPos;

        private int dimension;

        private Actions action;

        private PuzzleState father;
        private List<PuzzleState> children = new List<PuzzleState>();

        public IEnumerable<Search.Node> Neighbours
        {
            get
            {
                List<PuzzleState> temp = Expansion();
            //    List<Search.Node> converted = Convert(temp);
                return null;
            }
        }

    public PuzzleState(int dimension, States[,] iniStates, Actions lastAction, PuzzleState father)
    {
        actualState = new States[dimension, dimension];
        actualState = iniStates;

        this.action = lastAction;
        this.dimension = dimension;

        this.father = father;

        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
            {
                if (actualState[i, j] == States.Empty)
                {
                    empLinePos = i;
                    empColumPos = j;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

     public List<PuzzleState> Expansion()
        {
            List<PuzzleState> suns = new List<PuzzleState>();

            foreach (Actions item in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Actions)))
            {
                PuzzleState temp = SucessorFunc(item);
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    suns.Add(temp);
                }
            }

            return suns;
        }
        public PuzzleState SucessorFunc(Actions action)
        {
            this.action = action;
            switch (action)
            {
                case Actions.esquerda:

                    if (empColumPos > 0)
                    {
                        States[,] newPossibilities = Copy();

                        newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos] = newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos - 1];
                        newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos - 1] = States.Empty;

                        return new PuzzleState(dimension, newPossibilities, action, this);
                    }
                    break;
                case Actions.direita:

                    if (empColumPos < dimension - 1)
                    {
                        States[,] newPossibilities = Copy();

                        newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos] = newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos + 1];
                        newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos + 1] = States.Empty;

                        return new PuzzleState(dimension, newPossibilities, action, this);
                    }
                    break;
                case Actions.acima:

                    if (empLinePos > 0)
                    {
                        States[,] newPossibilities = Copy();

                        newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos] = newPossibilities[empLinePos - 1, empColumPos];
                        newPossibilities[empLinePos - 1, empColumPos] = States.Empty;

                        return new PuzzleState(dimension, newPossibilities, action, this);
                    }
                    break;
                case Actions.abaixo:

                    if (empLinePos < dimension - 1)
                    {
                        States[,] newPossibilities = Copy();

                        newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos] = newPossibilities[empLinePos + 1, empColumPos];
                        newPossibilities[empLinePos + 1, empColumPos] = States.Empty;

                        return new PuzzleState(dimension, newPossibilities, action, this);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return null;
        }

}
```

As I know this sounds crazy, I made a video showing this new C# effect:

http://youtu.be/gXQ6QyhMDDI

The code is only a .cs file and the link is here.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gc80ld47eps08nr/AAA3v-t-Jcv_-5CeDzxriLKua?dl=0

If anyone wants to check it out and tell me what the hell is going on here, I would appreciate.

Thanks.

Solution :

I found I way to go around with it by adding a string var called actionName. Every time I create a new PuzzleState I set its value as action.tostring(). But I still don`t know why the action value continuos to change the last item enum value.

The new code with the actionName variable and its set inside the constructor :

```
public class PuzzleState : Search.Node
        {
            private States[,] actualState;

            private int empLinePos;
            private int empColumPos;

            private int dimension;

            private Actions action;
            private string actionName;

            private PuzzleState father;
            private List<PuzzleState> children = new List<PuzzleState>();

            public IEnumerable<Search.Node> Neighbours
            {
                get
                {
                    List<PuzzleState> temp = Expansion();
                //    List<Search.Node> converted = Convert(temp);
                    return null;
                }
            }

        public PuzzleState(int dimension, States[,] iniStates, Actions lastAction, PuzzleState father)
        {
            actualState = new States[dimension, dimension];
            actualState = iniStates;
            this.actionName = lastAction.ToString();


            this.action = lastAction;
            this.dimension = dimension;

            this.father = father;

            for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
                {
                    if (actualState[i, j] == States.Empty)
                    {
                        empLinePos = i;
                        empColumPos = j;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

         public List<PuzzleState> Expansion()
            {
                List<PuzzleState> suns = new List<PuzzleState>();

                foreach (Actions item in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Actions)))
                {
                    PuzzleState temp = SucessorFunc(item);
                    if (temp != null)
                    {
                        suns.Add(temp);
                    }
                }

                return suns;
            }
            public PuzzleState SucessorFunc(Actions action)
            {
                this.action = action;
                switch (action)
                {
                    case Actions.esquerda:

                        if (empColumPos > 0)
                        {
                            States[,] newPossibilities = Copy();

                            newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos] = newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos - 1];
                            newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos - 1] = States.Empty;

                            return new PuzzleState(dimension, newPossibilities, action, this);
                        }
                        break;
                    case Actions.direita:

                        if (empColumPos < dimension - 1)
                        {
                            States[,] newPossibilities = Copy();

                            newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos] = newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos + 1];
                            newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos + 1] = States.Empty;

                            return new PuzzleState(dimension, newPossibilities, action, this);
                        }
                        break;
                    case Actions.acima:

                        if (empLinePos > 0)
                        {
                            States[,] newPossibilities = Copy();

                            newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos] = newPossibilities[empLinePos - 1, empColumPos];
                            newPossibilities[empLinePos - 1, empColumPos] = States.Empty;

                            return new PuzzleState(dimension, newPossibilities, action, this);
                        }
                        break;
                    case Actions.abaixo:

                        if (empLinePos < dimension - 1)
                        {
                            States[,] newPossibilities = Copy();

                            newPossibilities[empLinePos, empColumPos] = newPossibilities[empLinePos + 1, empColumPos];
                            newPossibilities[empLinePos + 1, empColumPos] = States.Empty;

                            return new PuzzleState(dimension, newPossibilities, action, this);
                        }
                        break;
                }

                return null;
            }

    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort with the video, but try to reduce your code sample to a minimum example that exerts the problem

Comment: I just put the parts, where the bizzar thing happen and the functions releated to it. Beleave me, the code is far bigger then that.

Comment: The code may be bigger, but it is your duty to be able to explain it in a concise way. Currently, you are just dumping the effort on other people who are nice enough to help you.

Comment: Why not step through with a debugger and watch the value of the variable?

Comment: Well, I actually did it and recorded in the video linked on the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `SuccessorFunc` you're setting the `action` member variable:

```
this.action = action;
```

So it will get set to each of the enum values as your `Expansion` method loops.